# How to make the 'week' starts with a specific day not Monday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In an application am building, i'm trying to make the week starts with Saturday. In ruby on rails, by default, the week begins on Monday.

So If you have any trick or a patch to make it work for me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly you want to do? where you want to use it? what you tried so far? we are not going to wite whole code for you. please explain in detail.

Comment: well, by default, in rails/ruby the week starts at Monday. What i want is to specify the begining of the week to Sunday for example!

Comment: people are becoming really snipey on this site...  the question seems fairly well explained to me.  the title made it all very clear.

Answer (score 10):

I've managed to make a pull request into rails and now you can pass symbol argument to `beginning_of_week` method. For example `beginning_of_week(:sunday)` will give you a Sunday assuming that week starts on Sunday. The same for `end_of_week` method. But you have to wait until rails 3.2 release in case you are not on the bleeding edge.

See this for more info:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3547

UPDATE:
Now I'm waiting for the new PR to be accepted, it makes possible to set default week start in your rails app config. See this for more info https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5339

UPDATE:

Merged!

```
rafaelfranca merged commit 5428de1 into rails:master from gregolsen:week_start_config 4 months ago
```

Closed
`rafaelfranca closed the pull request 4 months ag`o

Comment: congrats on getting that in. I have a bunch of failing tests around week start at the moment which implemented some ugly solution. This looks better.

Comment: Note that the following will end the week on friday evening at 23:59
    Time.now.end_of_week(:saturday)

Use :sunday for end_of_week to include saturday in the range.
    Time.now.end_of_week(:sunday)

Answer (score 4):

You could throw this into an initializer to make `beginning_of_week` return Sunday:

```
module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
  module CoreExtensions #:nodoc:
    module Time #:nodoc:
      module Calculations
        def beginning_of_week
          (self - self.wday.days).midnight
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It may be safer however for you to define your own method and leave the stock one intact:

```
module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
  module CoreExtensions #:nodoc:
    module Time #:nodoc:
      module Calculations
        def traditional_beginning_of_week
          (self - self.wday.days).midnight
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me on a 2.3.5 project, what version of Rails is your project running? Also, did you put it in a file under conifg/initializers/?

Comment: Well, how to make it returns Saturday?

Comment: Oh--looks like it's actually defined twice--in Date and Time--I would add both to avoid issues. `(self - self.wday.days).midnight` is Sunday, so `self - self.wday.days).midnight - 1.day` is Saturday, and so on.

Comment: I'm not testing any of this--I guess it would be `(self - self.wday.days - 1.day).midnight`. I don't know, play around with it, you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

You can try replacing `Date#wday` and `Time#wday` methods with your own. I think Rails' support methods like `beginning_of_week` etc. rely on wday and will work out of the box.

Here's some code, but it's definitely just an idea, neither tested nor recommended thing to do:

```
require 'activesupport'
#=> true
Time.now.wday
#=> 4
Time.now.beginning_of_week
#=> 2010-04-19 00:00:00 0200

class Time
  alias_method :orig_wday, :wday
  def wday 
    (self.orig_wday + 2) % 7
  end
end

Time.now.wday
#=> 6
Time.now.beginning_of_week
#=> 2010-04-17 00:00:00 0200
```

Comment: again, what i want is to specify the begining of the week to Sunday for example! in stead of rails default "Monday". Thanks

Comment: ammt - the code above will reset the start day to saturday (I think) - if you want to set it to Sunday, then just modify the line "(self.orig_wday +2) %7" to read:  "(self.orig_wday +1) %7" - the difference being the "+1" part...  use +3 for Friday, +4 for Thursday etc etc

Comment: it works well in the 'irb' but when I put it in the initializers folder in the rails application it deosnt affect! Am i did sth wrong?

When i try on Time.now it works and returns Saturday. But if i pick a record from the database to see beginning_of_week it returns Monday!

Comment: Perhaps you are checking `Date#beginning_of_week`? this code fixes only `Time` class. Anyway, I said that this was just an idea and not a ready solution you can just paste in your code and expect it to work. :(